# Compatible power supply for Radeon 280x Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

My friend and I just bought 2 Radeon 280x graphics cards, found here:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127759

In addition, we have an older PSU (http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=NPS-750AB-1-R).

The GPUs need a 6-pin PCIe and an 8-pin connector (both for power). Our PSU only has 4 6-pin connectors.

Is there a way to make this compatible, without lowering the potential of the GPUs (we don't want to use an adapter that might lower the power supply)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your power supply is not compatible with the graphic card you purchase.  You will need to replace it with something that is.

Comment: @Ramhound Do you mean just the connections themselves?

Comment: So we need a new PSU that can support the GPUs?

Comment: You need a PSU with 8-pin PCI-E power connectors.

Comment: Do I need to plug in both the 6-pin and the 8-pin PCI-E connectors? Because we have two adapters that allow us to plug an 8-pin in, but it uses 2 6-pin slots. So we could plug in an 8-pin connectors from both GPUs, but not the 6-pins...

Comment: If you have an adapter, that came with the graphic card I assume, then you have your answer.  Plug-in 2 6-pins into the adapter, the adapter into the graphic card, you left that important bit out.

Comment: We're trying that now. We'll be able to plug in the 8-pins then, but not the 6-pins...

Comment: You should read the manual its possible its one of those cases where its either the 6-pin or 8-pin connector.  The directions in the manual should indicate what should do exactly.